# Understanding Build error xcode Sandbox: bash(30970) deny(1) file-read-data

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't understand this error during xcode build:

Sandbox: bash(30970) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/.../ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-[name]/Pods-[name]-frameworks.sh

can anyone help me please?

Comment: I have exact the same problem at the moment. 
Using an Ionic App with Capacitor. 
Sandbox: bash(26268) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/.../ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh

Comment: @Kisimedia.de Yes, I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @Kisimedia.de, i reinitialized my config and it was ok for me. So, I didn't understand this error