Is there another solution to "Sandbox: rsync.samba(76010) deny(1) file-write-create error" rather than setting ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to NO?
I'm getting these errors when building my project in Xcode after installing mapbox:
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(76010) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/lluis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlpddtwcucwpygcxhthjwisifahq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject-Des.app/Frameworks/MapboxMaps.framework/MapboxMapsResources.bundle (in target 'MyProject-Des' from project 'MyProject')
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(76011) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/lluis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlpddtwcucwpygcxhthjwisifahq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject-Des.app/Frameworks/MapboxMaps.framework/.Info.plist.7j5Zxx (in target 'MyProject-Des' from project 'MyProject')
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(76011) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/lluis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlpddtwcucwpygcxhthjwisifahq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject-Des.app/Frameworks/MapboxMaps.framework/.MapboxMaps.rIRQea

I have tried with ChatGPT and checked lots of different places such as the following links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590131/error-while-build-ios-app-in-xcode-sandbox-rsync-samba-13105-deny1-file-w
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/759995
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoR-vopM1HY
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708282
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77660771/understanding-build-error-xcode-sandbox-bash30970-deny1-file-read-data
All of them end up with the same solution: setting ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to NO. And it seems to me that there's no other real solution on the net.
I've followed all the instructions, setting ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to NO, and clean up my project every time:
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ios/Pods
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install --repo-update

Although it actually worked for me, I was wondering if there was another work around while leaving ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to YES.
I understand this error happens in the building process when Xcode is trying to write files in a forbidden location, but I really don't get why this error should be happening at all.
I'm using the latest versions for ruby, Cocoapods, npm, Xcode, React-native, react-native-config, @rnmapbox/maps, firebase, etc.
Could it be that there is some sort of issue with these versions combined?
Should I downgrade some of these components versions?
Should I "tamper" with my building phases?
I'm using ruby "3.3.0", Xcode 15.4. The sistem is using Cocoapods 1.15.2 although my Gemfile looks like this:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# You may use http://rbenv.org/ or https://rvm.io/ to install and use this version
ruby "3.3.0"

# Cocoapods 1.15 introduced a bug which break the build. We will remove the upper
# bound in the template on Cocoapods with next React Native release.
gem 'cocoapods', '>= 1.13', '< 1.15'
gem 'activesupport', '>= 6.1.7.5', '< 7.1.0'


Maybe this comment (# Cocoapods 1.15 introduced a bug which break the build. We will remove the upper bound in the template on Cocoapods with next React Native release.) is the key?
This is MyPodfile:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'MyProject' do
  config = use_native_modules!

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static # Added following instructions for Firebase https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true # Added following instructions for Firebase https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  target 'MyProject-Des' do
    inherit! :complete
  end
  target 'MyProject-Pre' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

  # MAPBOX START
  pre_install do |installer|
  $RNMapboxMaps.pre_install(installer)
  end
  # MAPBOX END

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
    # MAPBOX START
    $RNMapboxMaps.post_install(installer)
    # MAPBOX END
  end
end


Thanks a lot in advance!

Did you find a different way to solve it? I'm facing the same Sandbox: rsync.samba to build my iOS product after macOS Sequoia upgrade. Even after downgrading Xcode to 15 and checking the versions of all the rest, the problem is here. Unfortunately ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING  is already NO without success for my problem.
